# ConEmu: split shortcut + broadcast shortcut

Tags: conemu

New to ConEmu and need help to do the following actions:

- How to set up a shortcut to open a new terminal as split, right or bottom ?! so far I can only do it via menu after many many clicks!
- How to set up ConEmu to startup with default splits: one large split on the left and 2 splits on the right top/bottom 50-50 ?
- How to broadcast a given command to all splits at one ? any shortcut to enable/disable broadcasting ?